# Какие книги читать для развития в сфере ИБ

Tags: книги

Собираюсь поступать на курс "информационная безопасность" ,хотел узнать в чем суть работы и какую литературу посоветуют.
изучал языки;

1. visual basic
2. C++
3. HTML(знаю основы)

Хватит ли набора этих языков или надо ещё изучать какие-то(какие?)

Comment: Описание метки `книги`: "Вопросы с рекомендациями литературы. НЕ ЗАДАВАЙТЕ НОВЫХ ВОПРОСОВ ПО ЭТОЙ МЕТКЕ.". В целом же, информационная безопасность подразумевает хорошее знание математики, а остальное с опытом.

Comment: В университете Вам все расскажут. И какие языки изучать, и какие книги читать,и в чем суть работы. :-) Помните, что сделать все нетрудно. Труднее узнать как сделать. Еще труднее узнать, где узнать как сделать. (С)